# Automatically save files in a particular folder using python

Tags: python, file, directory, directory-structure

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
user    date        lat         lon
Peter   2019-03-04  37.749798   -122.492301
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751028   -122.492291
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751698   -122.491701
Peter   2019-03-04  37.751800   -122.489748
David   2019-03-04  38.122893   -122.242051
David   2019-03-04  38.124108   -122.239079
David   2019-03-04  38.127434   -122.238672
Emma    2019-03-04  37.893635   -122.076538
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.536206   -121.997080
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.538044   -121.993153
Joyce   2019-03-04  37.540443   -121.991415
```

Using the loop below I am able to create four separate .html files that are named after the users in the `user` column (`Peter.html`, `David.html`, `Emma.html`, `Joyce.html`) and show the coordinates per user on a Folium map.

```
def create_user_map(user):
    #create the map
    return map

for user in users:
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    user_file = f"{user}.html"
    user_map.save(user_file)
```

Now I would like to automatically store these files in the folder structure below using python. How can I extend the loop above to achieve this?

```
Report/
├── Reports per date/ 
│   ├── 2019-03-01/
│   ├── 2019-03-02/
│   ├── 2019-03-03/
│   └── 2019-03-04/
│        └── Users/
│            └── Peter/
│                └── Peter.html
│            └── David/
│                └── David.html
│            └── Emma/
│                └── Emma.html
│            └── Joyce/
│                └── Joyce.html
│
└── Reports per month/
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that at some point you've pulled the date for each entry, likely when you're creating the map, so lets call that variable 'user_date'

```
import os

for user in users:
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    if os.direxists('./%/'%(user_date)):
        user_file = f"./%s/{user}.html"%(user_date)
    else:
        os.mkdir('./%/'%(user_date))
        user_file = f"./%s/{user}.html"%(user_date)
    user_map.save(user_file)
```

This should create the directory for each date (if it does not already exist), set the user_file, and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got to make the directories, you can automate this as follows:

```
import os

directories = ["Reports", "Reports/Reports per date"]
for directory in required_directories: # check if the directory exists
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory) # create the directory
```

You would also need to do the same thing for the date:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") # just an example for date
    if not os.path.isdir(f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}"):
        os.mkdir(directory) # create the directory
'''
Then for each user, you need to create the directory, then save the file:
'''
for user in users:
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    
    if not os.path.isdir(f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}/{user}"):
        os.mkdir(directory) # create the directory

    user_file = f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}/{user}/{user}.html"
    user_map.save(user_file)
```

Putting everything together:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def create_user_map(user):
    #create the map
    return map

# initialize directories
directories = ["Reports", "Reports/Reports per date"]
for directory in required_directories: 
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

# initialize date directory
date = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
    if not os.path.isdir(f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}"):
        os.mkdir(directory) 

# for each user create the map then save html file
for user in users:
    user_map = create_user_map(user)
    
    if not os.path.isdir(f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}/{user}"):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    user_file = f"Reports/Reports per date/{date}/{user}/{user}.html"
    user_map.save(user_file)
```